# How to get the device metadata info from google cloud iot core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I am quite new to google cloud services and I'm trying to get the device metadata that I have added to devices under a registry, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
device.firebase_id
```

is unknown where the device is my device and firebase_id is the added attribute to metadata.
and `device.metadata.firebase_id` throws this exception:

'google.protobuf.pyext._message.ScalarMapContainer' object has no attribute 'firebase_id'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`device.metadata` is a map, so I think you can retrieve the value with:

`device.metadata['firebase_id']`

Comment: Didn't really think of that.
thanks @GabeWeiss, worked like a charm.